# Write DataGridView to TextFile Duplicate Lines based on Grid Cell QTY

Tags: vb.net

I have a routine that produces a text file based on the contents of a DataGridView.

the scenario is this.
Sales Order line [Item Name[ [Quantity]

the solution is to produce a text file for each quantity. currently my routine only produces a line for each order line, not each quantity.

If for example its current row, column 6.

```
Try

        Dim StrExport As String = ""

        For Each C As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
            StrExport &= "" & C.HeaderText & ","
        Next
        StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
        StrExport &= Environment.NewLine

        For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            For Each C As DataGridViewCell In R.Cells
                If Not C.Value Is Nothing Then
                    StrExport &= "" & C.Value.ToString & ","
                Else
                    StrExport &= "" & "" & ","
                End If
            Next
            StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length - 1)
            StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
        Next

        Dim tw As IO.TextWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
        tw.Write(StrExport)
        tw.Close()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, "FRLSTicket.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

a sample row might be

SalesID,QTY,CustomerName,ItemID,Name,LegColour

SO1234567,3,John Smith ,Chair,Comfortable Blue Chair,Walnut

Comment: This code loops on every row of your grid and for each row extracts the value of every cell concatenating and separating them with a comma. It seems correct albeit I strongly suggest you to use a StringBuilder and not all those &= . Can you post an example of what you have on a row of this grid?

Comment: Thanks, Sample added at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry but I still cannot see any kind of error in processing that grid row. What is the output in the file for that row?

Comment: Hi Steve, the output would be 1 line. as above. the desired results would be 3 lines because there is a qty of 3. 

ive just overcome it now by changing the SQL Query that produces the data in the grid, so although I appreciate your comments, I'm kind of ok now.
whats the norm here, delete the Question or leave it for an answer for someone else? I dont want to break etiquette here, I know some people can be quite precious about it.